# SQL Server 2008 - need help on a antithetical query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to find out meter reading for given transaction day.  In some cases there won’t be any meter reading and would like to see a meter reading for previous day.

Sample data set follows. I am using SQL Server 2008

```
declare   @meter table (UnitID int, reading_Date date,reading int)
declare @Transactions table (Transactions_ID int,UnitID int,Transactions_date date)


insert into  @meter (UnitID,reading_Date,reading ) values 
(1,'1/1/2014',1000),
(1,'2/1/2014',1010),
(1,'3/1/2014',1020),
(2,'1/1/2014',1001),
(3,'1/1/2014',1002);

insert into  @Transactions(Transactions_ID,UnitID,Transactions_date) values
(1,1,'1/1/2014'),
(2,1,'2/1/2014'),
(3,1,'3/1/2014'),
(4,1,'4/1/2014'),
(5,2,'1/1/2014'),
(6,2,'3/1/2014'),
(7,3,'4/1/2014');

select * from @meter;
select * from @Transactions;
```

I expect to get following output

```
Transactions
Transactions_ID     UnitID  Transactions_date   reading 
1                   1       1/1/2014            1000
2                   1       2/1/2014            1010
3                   1       3/1/2014            1020
4                   1       4/1/2014            1020
5                   2       1/1/2014            1001
6                   2       3/1/2014            1001
7                   3       4/1/2014            1002
```

Comment: Add what you've tried so far as well as the desired output based on your sample data.

Comment: How do you define a "*previous day*"?  What if an alternative reading is not available as well?

Comment: Are you wanting to output each value from Transaction and the value from meter that is the most recent on or before the transactions_date?

Comment: This would be a better question if you a) provided sample output you're expecting, b) took a stab at showing what you've done so far and c) used sql fiddle so people could see and run your queries directly: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7dd78/2

Comment: Hi greg, yes that is the goal i want to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL Query to get your desired out put will as following:

```
SELECT Transactions_ID, T.UnitID, Transactions_date
, (CASE WHEN ISNULL(M.reading,'') = '' THEN 
         (
             SELECT MAX(Reading) FROM @meter AS A 
             JOIN @Transactions AS B ON A.UnitID=B.UnitID AND A.UnitID=T.UnitID 
         )
   ELSE M.reading END) AS Reading
FROM @meter AS M
RIGHT OUTER JOIN @Transactions AS T ON T.UnitID=M.UnitID 
AND T.Transactions_date=M.reading_Date
```

Comment: Hi Bhavesh, looks like outputs are not quite matching for last 2 transactions

Comment: Hi @blksdw, Thanks more making me attention on wrong output, I just correct it. can check.

Comment: I never knew you can use select statement in CASE statement. Your answer was very educational for me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to approach this - neither of them are ideal.

The first (and slightly better) way would be to create a SQL Function that took the Transactions_date as a parameter and returned the reading for Max(Reading_date) where reading_date <= transactions_date. You could then use this function in a select statement against the Transactions table.

The other approach would be to use a cursor to iterate through the transactions table and use the same logic as above where you return the reading for Max(Reading_date) where reading_date <= transactions_date.

Comment: Thanks greg. ill try writing a cursor and see

Comment: @blksdw Actually I think that Bhavesh Harsora's answer is likely to work - might require a bit of fine tuning but it's better than my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query:

Please find the result of the same in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3a0d8/1)

```
select a.Transactions_ID, a.UnitID, a.Transactions_date,
case when b.reading IS NULL then c.rd else b.reading end as reading
from
Transactions a 
left outer join
meter b 
on a.UnitID = b.UnitID
and a.Transactions_date = b.reading_Date
inner join 
(
select UnitID,max(reading) as rd
from meter
group by UnitID
) as C
on a.UnitID = c.UnitID
```